# Delete rows of local database as each is transfered to hosted database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

## EDIT - got the transfer to happen

.. now I need to figure out how to get the successful transfers to delete each row after it is stored on the host.  The function that grabs the data from the browsers SQL database is :

```
function grabLocal(){
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM entries', [], function(tx, results){ 
        var len = results.rows.length, i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        
        var qID = (results.rows.item(i).ID);
        var qEmail = (results.rows.item(i).email);
        var qPhone = (results.rows.item(i).phone);
        var qMonth = (results.rows.item(i).birth_month);
        var qDay = (results.rows.item(i).birth_day);
        var qYear = (results.rows.item(i).birth_year);
        var qMonth = (results.rows.item(i).birth_month);
        var qGender = (results.rows.item(i).gender);
        var qContest = (results.rows.item(i).contest);
        var qStore = (results.rows.item(i).storeNo);
        var qDate = (results.rows.item(i).added_on);
        var  localData = new Array((qEmail),(qPhone),(qMonth),(qDay),(qYear),(qGender),(qContest),(qStore),(qDate));
            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendIt.php",
            data: "email=" + qEmail + "&phone=" + qPhone + "&month=" + qMonth + "&day=" + qDay + "&year=" + qYear + "&gender=" + qGender + "&contest=" + qContest + "&store=" + qStore + "&date=" + qDate,
            success: function(){
                // delete each row as passed to host
                db.transaction(function(tx)
                {
                    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM entries WHERE ID = ?', [qID]);
                });
                
            //  alert ("Success");
            }
        });

  }
    });
  });
}
```

the php is simple like :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
$email  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));  
$phone  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));  
$month  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['month']));  
$day  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['day']));  
$year  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['year']));  
$gender  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['gender']));  
$contest  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['contest']));  
$store  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['store']));  
$datestamp  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['date']));  
mysql_select_db("sandbox_info") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `infoData` (email, phone, birth_month, birth_day, birth_year, gender, storeNo, contest, added_on) VALUES ('$email','$phone','$month','$day','$year','$gender','$store','$contest','$datestamp')");
echo 'Data uploaded';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Can someone please help explain what is wrong with the delete transaction?  It does delete one row each time I run the process but I would like it to delete all of them.  I guess I could drop the whole table but I would rather it runs a check after each transfer to the remote host and then deletes the local data.  I would also appreciate any tips on how this code could just be improved in general.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

## REVELATION

OK i echoed back the qID in the success and found out since it is deleting out each row it is then giving a new id to the next available row and keeps echoing out the same id over and over.  So... I know the problem but still need some help to find the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have described it well enough: if you already have HTTP POST support in your app (using java.net.URL or HttpClient) and a PHP script that works on the server, you'll need to:

1. Detect when someone is online (look at their IP address or try and connect to your server).
2. Generate a list of all unsaved transactions: you've got the basic code for that above, maybe you need some flag.
3. For each row, generate a POST to the server: if the POST succeeds (returns a 200 success code) then delete the row from the local database (or mark it as synchronized in some other way).

That should do it?

Comment: Hi Femi.. thanks for the explanation.  I am a lot closer.. went about it a bit different than you describe but do have the transfer working.  I updated my question as I am stumped on the piece to delete rows from the local.  Can you please elaborate on how I would write a statement to delete based on a 200 success?

Comment: Ah, glad to help. Just clarifying: you currently have single row deletes working and you are now trying to delete ALL successfully uploaded rows at the same time?

Comment: well... i am hoping to clear each row after it is succefully transferred... I tried  tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM entries');
and that works at deleting everything.. now I have different headaches but I still hope to find best solution for this

Comment: Try changing the DELETE statement to `DELETE FROM entries WHERE ID = ?` and see if that helps: the column names are case sensitive.

Comment: oh yea thanks.. i had tried that but I forgot to update my question... it did work but it only deletes one row and then quits

Comment: Well, that's what its supposed to do, no?

Comment: no sorry.. it goes through and moves all of the rows to the remote db but it only deletes the first row.. i think i figured out why is because when it deletes it, the id changes back to the one it just deleted.. does that make sense? So.. I need to have a different WHERE or else just figure out how to live with everything being deleted by removing the WHERE altogether

Comment: Odd. Perhaps because of the nesting transactions? If you change the second call to `db.transaction(function(tx2)
                {
                    tx2.executeSql('DELETE FROM entries WHERE ID = ?', [qID]);
                });` does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do but...

You could have one side generate a list of INSERT statements from the data that would be executed on the other side.

Comment: sorry I dont really understand.. to better explain when a user is offline the local db table will fill up with entries.  When they again reconnect I need to write something that will parse through all of the data and send it up to the server.  Does that make sense?